# Pairing similar filenames using Python

Tags: python, grouping

I have folder with files like these:

```
file1text_part1_morefile1text.ext
file1text_part2_morefile1text.ext
file2text_part1_morefile2text.ext
file2text_part2_morefile2text.ext
...
```

The output should be list of touples like this:

```
[(file1text_part1_morefile1text.ext, file1text_part2_morefile1text.ext), (...), ...]
```

I am trying to create a solution using loops and `os.split()`, but I am unable to get the correct list output. Do you have any advice or tips?

EDIT: Now I realize there could be more underscores in the filenames, for example `file_1_text_part1_morefile_1text.ext`. However the only thing that differs between those 2 files is the part1/part2.

Comment: `_partX_` is the only part of the filename that differs?

Comment: exactly, everything else is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take each file's stem (name without extension), extract everything except the `_partX_` as a common identifier and group the files by that:

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path

filenames = Path('/base/folder/').glob('*')
grouped = defaultdict(list)
for file in filenames:
    key = re.split(r'_part\d+_', file)
    grouped[tuple(key)].append(file)

for key, files in grouped.items():
    print(files)
```

Comment: Would it work if there were more underscores in the filenames? Edited the question

Comment: @user430953 I updated my code to extract everything except `_partX_`

Comment: @user430953 is this work for : `'file1text_part` , `'file_1_text_part`? you say these two must be in same group

Comment: @user1740577 OP specified that everything except `_partX_` is identical so I didn't do further processing like removal of underscores

Answer (score 1):

If you consider difference between `file_1_text` and `file1text` try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re


fl_nm = ['file1text_part1_morefile1text.ext', 'file1text_part2_morefile1text.ext' , 
         'file2text_part1_morefile2text.ext', 'file2text_part2_morefile2text.ext' , 
         'file_1_text_part1_morefile_1text.ext', 'file_1_text_part2_morefile_1text.ext']

dct = defaultdict(list)


for fn in fl_nm:
#     print()
    dct[fn.split('_part')[0]].append(fn)

# dct
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'file1text': ['file1text_part1_morefile1text.ext',
#               'file1text_part2_morefile1text.ext'],
#              'file2text': ['file2text_part1_morefile2text.ext',
#               'file2text_part2_morefile2text.ext'],
#              'file_1_text': ['file_1_text_part1_morefile_1text.ext',
#               'file_1_text_part2_morefile_1text.ext']
    
[tuple(v) for k,v in dct.items()]
```

Output:

```
[('file1text_part1_morefile1text.ext', 'file1text_part2_morefile1text.ext'),
 ('file2text_part1_morefile2text.ext', 'file2text_part2_morefile2text.ext'),
('file_1_text_part1_morefile_1text.ext','file_1_text_part2_morefile_1text.ext')]
```

Or if you **don't** consider difference between `file_1_text` and `file1text` try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

fl_nm = ['file1text_part1_morefile1text.ext', 'file1text_part2_morefile1text.ext' , 
         'file2text_part1_morefile2text.ext', 'file2text_part2_morefile2text.ext' , 
         'file_1_text_part1_morefile_1text.ext', 'file3text_part1_morefile2text.ext']

dct = defaultdict(list)


for fn in fl_nm:
    dct[re.findall(r'\d+' , re.findall(r'file(.*)text', fn)[0])[0]].append(fn)

# dct
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'1': ['file1text_part1_morefile1text.ext',
#               'file1text_part2_morefile1text.ext',
#               'file_1_text_part1_morefile_1text.ext'],
#              '2': ['file2text_part1_morefile2text.ext',
#               'file2text_part2_morefile2text.ext'],
#              '3': ['file3text_part1_morefile2text.ext']})

    
[tuple(v) for k,v in dct.items()]
```

Output:

```
[('file1text_part1_morefile1text.ext',
  'file1text_part2_morefile1text.ext',
  'file_1_text_part1_morefile_1text.ext'),
 ('file2text_part1_morefile2text.ext', 'file2text_part2_morefile2text.ext'),
 ('file3text_part1_morefile2text.ext',)]
```

Comment: Edited the question, there might be more underscores in the filenames, is it possible to make your solution work even then?

Answer (score 0):

Get all the filenames using `os.listdir(path)`. Iterate over each file_name & match against the pattern.

```
import os, re

def get_matched_files(path, pattern):
    matched_files = []

    for file_name in os.listdir(path=path):
        if re.match(pattern, file_name):
            matched_files.append(file_name)

    return matched_files


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = "./"
    pattern = "file(\d+)text_part(\d+)_morefile(\d+)text.ext"
    print(get_matched_files(path, pattern))
```

Output:

```
['file1text_part1_morefile1text.ext', 'file1text_part2_morefile1text.ext', 'file2text_part1_morefile2text.ext', 'file2text_part2_morefile2text.ext']

Process finished with exit code 0
```